# How to get ratings from a bookstoscrape website and feed it into database

Tags: python, sql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

Currently, I'm trying to get ratings from a website called [bookstoscrape](https://books.toscrape.com/) and feed it into a database as a practice, but there's an error raised:

> InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sqlite3
import re

conn = sqlite3.connect('scraped.db')
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute(''' CREATE TABLE CATEGORY(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,NAME TEXT)''')
curs.execute(''' CREATE TABLE BOOKS(Category_Id INTEGER, NAME TEXT,PRICE INTEGER,RATING TEXT)''')

html_content = requests.get('http://books.toscrape.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.content)

url = "http://books.toscrape.com/"

def getURLs(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    return(soup)
def getBooks(url):
    soup = getURLs(url)
    # remove the index.html part of the base url before returning the results
    return(["/".join(url.split("/")[:-1]) + "/" + x.find("div").find("a").get('href') for x in soup.findAll("article", attrs = {"class":"product_pod"})])

pages_urls = []
new_page = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html"

while requests.get(new_page).status_code == 200:
    pages_urls.append(new_page)
    new_page = pages_urls[-1].split("-")[0] + "-" + str(int(pages_urls[-1].split("-")[1].split(".")[0]) + 1) + ".html"

booksURLs = []
for page in pages_urls:
    booksURLs.extend(getBooks(page))

names = []
prices = []
rate = []
for x in range(len(booksURLs)):
    soup = getURLs(url)
    all_articles = soup.find_all("article", attrs = {"class":"product_pod"})

    for article in all_articles:
        
        names.append(soup.find("article", class_ = ("product_pod")).find("h3").get_text())
        prices.append(soup.find("p", class_ = "price_color").text[2:]) # get rid of the pound sign
        rate.append(soup.find("article", class_ = ("product_pod")).find('p').get('class')[1])

        curs.execute("INSERT INTO BOOKS VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(x,names,prices,rate))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please provide sufficient code snippet so that we can run it successfully on our machines. Your code is missing definition of some variables and lacking some import statements

Comment: Do you understand what the error message *means*, at the most immediate level?

Answer (score 0):

names, prices and rate variables are lists, so this:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO BOOKS VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(x,names,prices,rate))
```

must become this:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO BOOKS VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(x,names[0],prices[0],rate[0]))
```

Comment: Although It's working, this will feed SQL with only the first element only not all the names, prices nor the rates the only thing that will work is the x value

Comment: Well you can't use lists, so convert them to a string using join() method and then insert them into the table.

Comment: That totally doesn't work it just repeat the name for n times for each n iteration